AdonisJS 6 REST API social auth for React (TS) Front end
I'm using AdonisJS 6 to create a REST API for my web app (and mobile app in the future). The user can login using email + password or Google (OAuth).
My API is running in URL https://api.example.com and frontend https://app.example.com
The idea of Google login should be pretty basic.

Open the flow by clicking Google button
REST API handles the redirect and response --> creates HTTP-Only cookie and redirects back to FE url

This is my current auth_google_controller.ts
import type { HttpContext } from '@adonisjs/core/http'
import User from '#models/user'
import env from '#start/env'
import { isUniqueProvider } from '../../guards/auth_provider_guard.js'
import { AuthProviders } from '../../enums/auth_providers.enum.js'

export default class AuthGoogleController {
  async redirect({ ally }: HttpContext) {
    return ally.use('google').redirect()
  }

  async callback({ ally, response }: HttpContext) {
    const google = ally.use('google')

    try {
      if (google.accessDenied()) {
        return response.badRequest('Access was denied')
      }

      if (google.hasError()) {
        return response.badRequest(google.getError() || 'Something went wrong')
      }

      const googleUser = await google.user()

      const isProviderVerified = await isUniqueProvider(googleUser.email, AuthProviders.google)

      if (!isProviderVerified) {
        return `Already exists on other provider`
      }

      // Find or create user
      const user = await User.firstOrCreate(
        { email: googleUser.email },
        {
          email: googleUser.email,
          fullName: googleUser.name,
          provider: 'google',
          providerId: googleUser.id,
        }
      )

      // Generate token
      const token = await User.accessTokens.create(user, ['*'], {
        expiresIn: env.get('JWT_EXPIRY'),
      })

      // Convert JWT_EXPIRY to number and calculate maxAge in milliseconds
      const jwtExpiryInSeconds = Number.parseInt(env.get('JWT_EXPIRY', '3600'), 10)
      const maxAgeInMilliseconds = jwtExpiryInSeconds * 1000

      // Set HTTP-only cookie with the token
      response.cookie('auth_token', token.value!.release(), {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        maxAge: maxAgeInMilliseconds,
      })

      // Redirect to the frontend
      const frontendCallbackUrl = 'https://app.example.com/auth/google/callback'
      return response.redirect().toPath(frontendCallbackUrl)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return response.internalServerError('An unexpected error occurred')
    }
  }
}


and this is FE Google button
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@mantine/core";
import { useCallback } from "react";

export function GoogleButton(
  props: ButtonProps & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"button">
) {

  const handleGoogleLogin = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      window.location.href = "https://api.example.com/v1/auth/google/redirect";
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error initiating Google login:", error);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={handleGoogleLogin}
      leftSection={<GoogleIcon />}
      variant="default"
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

function GoogleIcon(props: React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"svg">) {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
      viewBox="0 0 256 262"
      style={{ width: "0.9rem", height: "0.9rem" }}
      {...props}
    >
      <path
        fill="#4285F4"
        d="M255.878 133.451c0-10.734-.871-18.567-2.756-26.69H130.55v48.448h71.947c-1.45 12.04-9.283 30.172-26.69 42.356l-.244 1.622 38.755 30.023 2.685.268c24.659-22.774 38.875-56.282 38.875-96.027"
      />
      <path
        fill="#34A853"
        d="M130.55 261.1c35.248 0 64.839-11.605 86.453-31.622l-41.196-31.913c-11.024 7.688-25.82 13.055-45.257 13.055-34.523 0-63.824-22.773-74.269-54.25l-1.531.13-40.298 31.187-.527 1.465C35.393 231.798 79.49 261.1 130.55 261.1"
      />
      <path
        fill="#FBBC05"
        d="M56.281 156.37c-2.756-8.123-4.351-16.827-4.351-25.82 0-8.994 1.595-17.697 4.206-25.82l-.073-1.73L15.26 71.312l-1.335.635C5.077 89.644 0 109.517 0 130.55s5.077 40.905 13.925 58.602l42.356-32.782"
      />
      <path
        fill="#EB4335"
        d="M130.55 50.479c24.514 0 41.05 10.589 50.479 19.438l36.844-35.974C195.245 12.91 165.798 0 130.55 0 79.49 0 35.393 29.301 13.925 71.947l42.211 32.783c10.59-31.477 39.891-54.251 74.414-54.251"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}

Is this correct approach or should I use something else?

Other questions:
 1. How do I handle the API response on FE side? 
 2. How does the API know that user is signed-in when I'm trying to fetch data from another route after this login?


